# C# .exe upload of multiple files to PHP server - filename param?

Tags: c#, php, file, upload, file-upload

What is the best way for a C# .exe program, to upload to a php server script that accepts file uploads.

If using .NET WebClient is the only way, is there a way for WebClient to specify the parameter name, rather than just the file?

For example, the C# .exe would do basically what a simple html form would do in this case.

`<input name="filename" type="file" />`

How do you specify this name parameter using WebClient?

Comment: Wouldn't that be `name="file"`? That's what I'm getting. And if you're sending it to a PHP script multiple files, make sure the name ends in `[]`, as in `name="files[]"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [UploadFileEx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uploadfileex.aspx) from CodeProject.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this with the HttpWebRequest class.  It's a bit tricky since you will most likely need to upload the file using MIME multipart formatting.  However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) explains this process much better than I can: [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Good luck to you :)

Comment: From that same post, check out this guy's blog: http://aspnetupload.com/Upload-File-POST-HttpWebRequest-WebClient-RFC-1867.aspx.

Looks like his UploadHelper class has the code built for doing this procedure already.